# MySQL, puzzled why query is slow, have an index?

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I'm puzzled why one of my queries is slow, I have indexes and I've just created a new one.

Yet its still been quite slow and appears in my slow log.

Heres my query...

```
  SELECT *, 
         COUNT( Word ) AS WordCount 
    FROM `keywords` 
   WHERE `LetterIdx` = 'A' 
GROUP BY Word 
ORDER BY Word;
```

Heres the query EXPLAIN'd

[image]
Heres my table structure and indexes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it runs a lot faster like this, if you create a composite index across (LetterIdx, Word) it may help more.  This is a 2-column index instead of 2 single-column indexes

```
CREATE INDEX keywords_l_w on keywords(letterIdx, Word)

SELECT Word, 
     COUNT( Word ) AS WordCount 
FROM `keywords` 
WHERE `LetterIdx` = 'A' 
GROUP BY Word 
ORDER BY Word;
```

If my guess is correct that LetterIdx = first letter of Word, this may work even better

```
# First create index on Word, then 
SELECT Word, 
     COUNT( Word ) AS WordCount 
FROM `keywords` 
WHERE `Word` like 'A%' 
GROUP BY Word 
ORDER BY Word;
```

As for *"I'm puzzled why one of my queries is slow, I have indexes and I've just created a new one."*

It is because you have asked it to retrieve all columns of the record.  Is that really necessary? Even if it can use the index (~ 1/26 of all data), it will still need to look up the data pages to retrieve all other columns.  If you had a covering index (letteridx, word), it does not need to go back to the data.

For what it's worth, * and GROUP BY are not a good mix in a strict SQL sense.

Comment: The only problem is that with LetterIdx A I also include numbers. so A% wouldn't included these. Your first query didn't make any difference to the speed. Any further ideas ?

Comment: have you created the index on (letteridx, word)? any chance of an EXPLAIN for that too?

Comment: Note that the index is across 2 columns, not 2 single-column indexes. Answer updated. FYI, the order does matter, (Word, LI) != (LI, Word)

Answer (score 0):

Try a compound index on (LetterIdx, Word)

It should then be able to use the index for both that speciofc where clause, and that specific group by/order by

Comment: I already have an index on word and letteridx as shown above.

Comment: like cyberkiwi mentioned, the order of the columns in the index matters., It dictates the way the index is physically stored, which dictates the ways it can, and cannot be efficiently used.

Answer (score 0):

Like Richard said, you should use a compound index with LetterIdx and Word.

But I sugest you to do this query:

```
SELECT Word, COUNT( * ) AS WordCount
FROM `keywords`
WHERE `LetterIdx` = 'A'
GROUP BY Word
```

Since, GROUP BY ordered the columns, you could do this: `GROUP BY Word DESC` you don't have the need to use ORDER BY ...